# React Material UI TextField hover mouse icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, mousehover, mouse-cursor

I want to change the default mouse cursor behavior of TextField of Material UI component when the TextField has variant="outlined". In such case the cursor is Text and I want to have it as a pointer. I tried to override it as the below but it did not work. I also changed MuiInputBase into TextField and still it did not work

```
  const myTheme = createTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiInputBase: {
        root: {
          '&:hover:': {
            cursor: "pointer"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

and then later in my provider :

```
<ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
   <TextField variant="outlined"/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `root` to `input`

```
MuiInputBase: {
  input: {
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Thank you Viet. Could you please let me know how you got which selector should be chosen? I used google chrome dev tools and when I hover it I saw MuiInputBase-root and many more classes are triggered. Thanks

Comment: You can search property `cursor` and saw it in `input`

Comment: When I search I mainly see cursor on MuiInputBase-root